# I just installed a Ubuntu Hardy server. In Python, I tried to import _mysql and MySQLdb

Tags: python, linux, unix, installation

But, they were unable to be found!?

How do I install both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed python-mysqldb? If not install it using **apt-get install python-mysqldb**. And how are you importing mysql.Is it **import MySQLdb**? Python is case sensitive.

Comment: When I do import MySQLdb, it will give me an error ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 3, 'gamma', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 2, 'final', 0)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server    
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should make it work:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Comment: I did this, but when I import MySQLdb, it gave me that _mysql was out of date or something?

Comment: Does it report "DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated"?